# Rails Routes - Having two different routes show same information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-api

I have two different models: User and Organization, orgs for short.  I would like both to be able to create posts, so both have a one-to-many relationships with Post model.

I set my table as such:

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "likes"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "org_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

My routes:

```
      resources :users do
        resources :posts
      end

      resources :orgs do 
        resources :posts 
        resources :users
      end
```

My Outcome

```
// http://localhost:3001/api/v1/**users**/4/posts

[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "content": "This a user's post",
    "likes": 0,
    "user_id": 4,
    "org_id": null,
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "content": "This is an org's post",
    "likes": 0,
    "user_id": null,
    "org_id": 2,
  }
]
```

I am able to post as a user and as an org, however when I route to either my user or org, it shows the post for both.

Is there a way to show only user's post when route to user and only org's post when route to orgs?

Comment: show your controller code

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .where queries example:

```
# showing posts for a user who's ID is 4:
user_4_posts = Post.where(user_id: 4)
```

user_4_posts will be and array of posts which have a user_id of 4

here's a link with more examples: [Link](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/07/rails-where-method/)

Hopefully this helps but maybe i misunderstood your question

Answer (score 1):

### Two separate controller actions are needed

We need to see your controller code. This is not an issue to do with your routes, that much. This more of a controller problem.

I would actually have two separate controllers: `Posts::Organisations` and another `Posts::Users` (don't use those names and the way I've set it up - I'm kinda annoyed with how it sits, but it might give you some ideas:)

```
# Untested code: i typed it in the editor, so there might be typos
# app/controllers/posts/organisations_controller.rb
module Posts
   class OrganisationsController < ApplicationController
     def index
       @organisation = Organisation.find(params[:organisation_id])
       @posts = @organisation.posts  # you might want to paginate this
     end
   end
end

# app/controllers/posts/users_controller.rb
module Posts
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
     def index
       @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
       @posts = @user.posts  # you might want to paginate this
     end
   end
end
```

And with your routes, you could have something like this:

```
  get "organisations/:organisation_id/posts", to: "posts/organisations#index", as: "organisation_posts"
  get "users/:user_id/posts", to: "posts/users#index", as: "user_posts"
```

The point is you probably need two separate controllers, or two separate actions to handle the situation where you want to see organisation posts, and user posts.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!